# Точность вычислений. Си

Tags: c, округление

Мне нужно, чтобы по завершению программы число было выведено с точностью до 10^(-6) символов.
Но возникла проблема. Число не точное.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{int a,r;
float rad,x;
        scanf("%d" "%d", &a,&r);
        rad = (a/2) * (M_PI/180);
x = (r*(1+sin(rad)))/(1-sin(rad));
    printf("%f",x);
    return 0;
}
```

После завершения этой программы выдает значение 30.000002 , хотя должно выдавать 30.000000

(a = 60, r = 10)

Я попытался ограничить количество цифр после запятой до 5, но это не помогло.

Comment: `printf("%.5f"`... См. https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf. А для расчетов используйте `double`.

Comment: А я что говорил о `double`?  https://ideone.com/2CeAW0

Comment: И, кстати, делите на `2.`, не на `2`, а то введете нечетное значение и будете удивляться...

Comment: Странная идея вводить `a` и `r` целыми.

Comment: Вы хорошо понимаете что делает запись `"%d" "%d"` ?

Answer (score 2):

Семи разрядов точности `float` не хватает для вашей задачи: `30.000000` - восемь знаков. Используйте `double` - 16 разрядов.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

// В стандартном C нет константы M_PI, определяем на всякий случай
#ifndef M_PI
#  define M_PI (3.14159265358979323846)
#endif

int main() {
    // разумно ввести угол и радиус как вещественные числа
    // всегда все вещественные вычисления делайте на double
    // у вас не причин использовать float
    double a, r;

    // ввод всегда следует проверять
    if (scanf("%lf %lf", &a, &r) != 2) {
        fputs("error\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }

    // синус нужен два раза, запомним его
    // все константы в вещественных выражениях с точкой
    // целочисленное деление свело с ума не одного программиста
    const double s = sin(a / 2. * (M_PI / 180.));

    const double x = r * (1. + s) / (1. - s);

    // после печати переведите строку
    // печать вещественных чисел выводит шесть знаков после запятой,
    // ничего не надо менять
    printf("%lf\n", x);
}
```

Компилировать лучше на максимуме предупреждений. Компилятор замечает такие огрехи в коде, которые программисту и в голову не придут:

> ```
> $ gcc -std=c11 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wwrite-strings -Wconversion temp.c -lm
>
> $ echo 60 10 | ./a.out
> 30.000000
> ```

Comment: Если уж быть совсем педантом: 1 - я предлагаю использовать long double; 2 - Константа числа PI  (да и все значения с точкой) лучше завершать "L" (указание, что константа long double); 3 - PI/180 - это тоже константа, вычислите её сразу и внесите в определение возле PI, незачем каждый раз считать; 4 - Скобки в определении PI - лишние

Comment: Интересно, это в каком же компиляторе при операции над целым и плавающим, целое перед ней не преобразуется в плавающее?

Comment: @avp, ни в каком. Главное в процессе рефакторинга не заменить последний вещественный аргумент деления на целый. Было `a / 2`, всё работало. Поменяли тип `a` на `int` и получили кривое деление. С `a / 2.` такого не будет. Правило большого пальца: обходится без приведений там где можно без них обходится. Даже если это приведение константы.

Comment: Спорная методика. В пределе такое "превентивное заметание мусора под коврик" приводит к бездумному программированию (со всеми вытекающими ... )